Got non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Invalid Schnorr signature) error message when spend a taproot transation
I'm trying to spend an Taproot address via a key spend path with musig2 lib in Rust. This address is aggregated with 2 owners. But I still got this message when I broadcast the hex transaction to https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/push
 sendrawtransaction RPC error: {"code":-26,"message":"non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Invalid Schnorr signature)"}

The logic to create this transaction is that. First I need to create a deposit transaction that contains that aggregated address as output.
Here the code to create the aggregated address :
pub fn aggregate_pubkeys(
    owner_pubkey: PublicKey,
    se_pubkey: PublicKey,
) -> (PublicKey, PublicKey, Address, KeyAggContext) {
    let secp = Secp256k1::new();
    let mut pubkeys: Vec<PublicKey> = vec![];
    pubkeys.push(owner_pubkey);
    pubkeys.push(se_pubkey);
    let key_agg_ctx_tw = KeyAggContext::new(pubkeys.clone())
        .unwrap()
        .with_unspendable_taproot_tweak()
        .unwrap();

    let aggregated_pubkey: PublicKey = key_agg_ctx_tw.aggregated_pubkey_untweaked();
    let aggregated_pubkey_tw: PublicKey = key_agg_ctx_tw.aggregated_pubkey();

    let aggregated_address = Address::p2tr(
        &secp,
        aggregated_pubkey.x_only_public_key().0,
        None,
        Network::Testnet,
    );

    (
        aggregated_pubkey,
        aggregated_pubkey_tw,
        aggregated_address,
        key_agg_ctx_tw,
    )
}

Then I use the aggregated pub key to create the scriptpubkey for the output to the deposit transaction :
let agg_scriptpubkey = ScriptBuf::new_p2tr(&secp, agg_pubkey.x_only_public_key().0, None);
let utxo = TxOut {
    value: Amount::from_sat(amount),
    script_pubkey: agg_scriptpubkey,
};

aggregated_pubkey_tw and key_agg_ctx_tw are used to create the aggregated signature. I follow this document to create the signature https://docs.rs/musig2/latest/musig2/
here the code to create the spend transaction :

pub async fn create_bk_tx(
    pool: &PoolWrapper,
    conn: &NodeConnector,
    key_agg_ctx: &KeyAggContext,
    agg_pubkey: &PublicKey,
    agg_pubkey_tw: &PublicKey,
    agg_address: &Address,
    receiver_address: &str,
    txid: &str,
    vout: u32,
    amount: u64,
    statechain_id: &str,
) -> Result<()> {
    let secp = Secp256k1::new();
    let seckey = pool
        .get_seckey_by_id(&statechain_id)
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .unwrap();
    let seckey = SecretKey::from_str(&seckey).unwrap();

    // CREATE UNSIGNED TRANSACTION
    let agg_scriptpubkey = ScriptBuf::new_p2tr(&secp, agg_pubkey.x_only_public_key().0, None);
   
    let prev_outpoint = OutPoint {
        txid: txid.parse().unwrap(),
        vout: vout.into(),
    };

    let input = TxIn {
        previous_output: prev_outpoint,
        script_sig: ScriptBuf::default(),
        sequence: Sequence::ENABLE_RBF_NO_LOCKTIME,
        witness: Witness::default(),
    };

    let output_address = Address::from_str(receiver_address).unwrap();
    let checked_output_address = output_address.require_network(Network::Testnet).unwrap();
    let spend = TxOut {
        value: Amount::from_sat(amount - BASE_TX_FEE),
        script_pubkey: checked_output_address.script_pubkey(),
    };

    let mut unsigned_tx = Transaction {
        version: transaction::Version::TWO,  // Post BIP-68.
        lock_time: absolute::LockTime::ZERO, // Ignore the locktime.
        input: vec![input],                  // Input goes into index 0.
        output: vec![spend],                 // Outputs, order does not matter.
    };

    let utxo = TxOut {
        value: Amount::from_sat(amount),
        script_pubkey: agg_scriptpubkey,
    };

    let prevouts = vec![utxo];
    let prevouts = Prevouts::All(&prevouts);
    let mut sighasher = SighashCache::new(&mut unsigned_tx);

    let sighash_type = TapSighashType::All;
    let sighash = sighasher
        .taproot_key_spend_signature_hash(0, &prevouts, sighash_type)
        .expect("failed to construct sighash");

    let message = sighash.to_string();

    let parsed_msg = message.clone();
    let msg_clone = parsed_msg.clone();
    let msg = parsed_msg.clone();


    // MUSIG 2 TO CREATE SIGNATURE ON THE UNSIGNED TRANSACTION

    let get_nonce_res = statechain::get_nonce(&conn, statechain_id, &signed_statechain_id).await?; // API to get nonce from the server
    let server_pubnonce = get_nonce_res.server_nonce;

    let nonce_seed = [0xACu8; 32];

    let secnonce = SecNonce::build(nonce_seed).with_seckey(seckey).build();

    let our_public_nonce = secnonce.public_nonce();

    let public_nonces = [
        our_public_nonce,
        server_pubnonce.parse::<PubNonce>().unwrap(),
    ];

    let agg_pubnonce: AggNonce = public_nonces.iter().sum();

    let agg_pubnonce_str = agg_pubnonce.to_string();

    let our_partial_signature: PartialSignature = musig2::sign_partial(
        &key_agg_ctx,
        seckey,
        secnonce,
        &agg_pubnonce,
        message,
    )
    .expect("error creating partial signature");

    let serialized_key_agg_ctx = key_agg_ctx
        .to_bytes()
        .to_hex_string(bitcoin::hex::Case::Lower);

    let get_sign_res = statechain::get_partial_signature(
        &conn,
        &serialized_key_agg_ctx,
        &statechain_id,
        &signed_statechain_id,
        &msg_clone,
        &agg_pubnonce_str,
    )
    .await?; // API to request the partial signature from the server

    let server_signature = get_sign_res.partial_signature;

    let partial_signatures = [
        our_partial_signature,
        PartialSignature::from_hex(&server_signature).unwrap(),
    ];

    let final_signature: secp256k1::schnorr::Signature = musig2::aggregate_partial_signatures(
        &key_agg_ctx,
        &agg_pubnonce,
        partial_signatures,
        msg_clone,
    )
    .expect("error aggregating signatures");
    musig2::verify_single(*agg_pubkey_tw, final_signature, msg)
        .expect("aggregated signature must be valid");

    let signature = bitcoin::taproot::Signature {
        sig: final_signature,
        hash_ty: sighash_type,
    };

    let mut wit = Witness::new();
    wit.push(signature.to_vec());
    *sighasher.witness_mut(0).unwrap() = wit;

    let tx = sighasher.into_transaction();

    let tx_hex = consensus::encode::serialize_hex(&tx); // the final transaction to broadcast
   
    Ok(())
}

The signature pass the musig2 verification but not the node verification. I think the problem can relate to the sighash message that I request to sign. Here the deposit transaction and the spend transaction generated from the code. Any thoughts or help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you in advance!
deposit tx hex : 
02000000000101adbc7f34e1e97d380be4056b77843588f0bf15549ee6044eec203d52108dd0c30000000000ffffffff02ec13000000000000225120d0d489a32e40e1fa4811aae37c0f1661b27f295bf7bb9d6725a80b17347306675b07000000000000160014c9da028a0c782cbd1c20210e6a80592210fb190c0247304402201633ac94ab0c6561cd48244129a59c03d1b0acfc59cf141ee723ba1755b1376d02202ba6003fd635dca60e68f03b5a01567d71c73eeac23fa5cf0d89d2ef359cde400121030253610ad0dd0958c56cd4a2865fb3c2b333c12eaa5a7c5986c324543e186b3800000000

Spend tx hex : 
020000000001010412ef1c75adf318b320982fb31824d9da843fc4ec3b80af12846ec0893b7b440000000000fdffffff016400000000000000160014c9da028a0c782cbd1c20210e6a80592210fb190c0141ca1633ea01751f2b5e66330cd54a2cae88a5e92901a2a3261e266a1392685780d48f511309b0d3d2e2828409948723180d1be3a597ca55df12aeaddbed2008280100000000


